# Paint alpha mask bitmap as specific color

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

How do you paint an alpha mask image/`Bitmap` as a specific color. I'm trying to multiply the alpha (white) on the image by a color and draw it.

A couple examples of masks:

[Simple](http://ak6.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/712210/preview/stock-footage-looping-butterfly-animation-with-alpha-mask-isolated-on-white.jpg)

[Translucent](http://en.clipdealer.com/preview/image/001/836/658/previews/21--1836658-Explosion%20with%20sparks%20on%20black.%202%20versions%20-%20with%20and%20without%20flash.%20Alpha%20mask.%20HD%201080..jpg)

I'd like to have the black be transparent and the alpha/white be the color.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447834

Answer (score 0):

black = 0x00ffffff
white = 0xffffffff

The first two hex chars of a 32bit value of ARGB determine your alpha

```
    final int FULL_ALPHA = 0xFF000000;

    int pixel = FULL_ALPHA + some_value;
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(pixel);
    c.drawCircle(width, height, radius, p);
```

Comment: 0x00fffff is fully transparent WHITE, not BLACK.

Comment: Hi. Not sure where that uses an alpha mask bitmap. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found my answer, thanks to @petey.

```
Paint colorMultiplier = new Paint();
colorMultiplier.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffFilter(Color.parseColor("#123456"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
canvas.drawBitmap(alphaMask, 0, 0, colorMultiplier);
```